# Parse error missing : after property id

Tags: javascript

I am using some simple javascript as below, but for some reasn the catParam is failing with error missing : after id. please help.

```
var catParam = "(id=cat00000)";
var inputParams = {serviceID:"getCategories",apiKey="asdfasfgx6",catCriterior:catParam};
```

Comment: `apiKey="asdfasfgx6"` should be `apiKey : "asdfasfgx6"`

Comment: That's invalid javascript, in an object the `:` sign seperates the keys and values, not the equal sign

Comment: juvian, your suggestion worked thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
var catParam = "(id=cat00000)";
var inputParams = {serviceID:"getCategories",apiKey : "asdfasfgx6",catCriterior:catParam};
```

Instead - you are using an `=` instead of a `:` in your object literal. You assign properties of objects in literals using `:`.

[Check out more info here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals)

**Future reference**

- Try [JsHint](http://jshint.com) or [JsLint](http://jslint.com) to verify your code!
- Also, if you have clean and organized code, it can make it easier to spot small errors like this, as well as improve the error messages you get (as your error will likely be on a shorter line). Using tools like [JsBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) can get this done easily.

This would be your code after going through JS Beautifier:

```
var catParam = "(id=cat00000)";
var inputParams = {
    serviceID: "getCategories",
    apiKey: "asdfasfgx6",
    catCriterior: catParam
};
```